# How to grep a word exactly

Tags: r, regex

I'd like to grep for "nitrogen" in the following character vector and want to get
back only the entry which is containing "nitrogen" and nothing of the rest (e.g. nitrogen fixation):

```
varnames=c("nitrogen", "dissolved organic nitrogen", "nitrogen fixation", "total dissolved nitrogen", "total nitrogen")
```

I tried something like this:

```
grepl(pattern= "![[:space:]]nitrogen![[:space:]]", varnames)
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: So you just want the index/indices of the values that exactly equal "nitrogen"?  Does `which(varnames == "nitrogen")` give you what you want?

Comment: Dason: can you make your comment an answer so Sabsirro can accept?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the indices that are exactly equal to "nitrogen" you could use

```
which(varnames == "nitrogen")
```

Depending on what you want to do you might not even need the 'which' as `varnames == "nitrogen"` gives a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE.  If you just want to do something like replace all of the occurances of "nitrogen" with "oxygen" this should suffice

```
varnames[varnames == "nitrogen"] <- "oxygen"
```

Answer (score 14):

Although Dason's answer is easier, you could do an exact match using grep via:

```
varnames=c("nitrogen", "dissolved organic nitrogen", "nitrogen fixation", "total dissolved nitrogen", "total nitrogen")

grep("^nitrogen$",varnames,value=TRUE)
[1] "nitrogen"

grep("^nitrogen$",varnames)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Danson's answer is not just easier, it is also faster.

Comment: It works, but it's slow. Unless you're constructing `regex`es dynamically, there's no much sense in doing `^someword$`.

Answer (score 2):

Or use `fixed = TRUE` if you want to match actual string (`regex`lessly):

```
v <- sample(c("nitrogen", "potassium", "hidrogen"), size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.8, .1, .1))
grep("nitrogen", v, fixed = TRUE)
# [1]   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  11  12  13  14  16  19  20  21  22  23  24  25
# [20]  26  27  29  31  32  35  36  38  39  40  41  43  44  46  47  48  49  50  51
# [39]  52  53  54  56  57  60  61  62  65  66  67  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76
# [58]  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  91  92  93  94  95  96  97
# [77]  98  99 100
```

Dunno about the speed issues, I like to test stuff and claim that approach A is faster than approach B, but in theory, at least from my experience, indexing/binary operators should be the fastest, so I vote for @Dason's approach. Also note that `regex`es are **always** slower than `fixed = TRUE` `grep`ing.

A little proof is attached bellow. Note that this is a lame test, and `system.time` should be put inside `replicate` to get (more) accurate differences, you should take outliers into an account, etc. But surely this one proves that you should use `which`! =)

```
(a0 <- system.time(replicate(1e5, grep("^nitrogen$", v))))
# user  system elapsed 
# 5.700   0.023   5.724  
(a1 <- system.time(replicate(1e5, grep("nitrogen", v, fixed = TRUE))))
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.147   0.020   1.168 
(a2 <- system.time(replicate(1e5, which(v == "nitrogen"))))
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.013   0.020   1.033
```

Comment: He, tanks for that detailed answer. It is good to know about this differences.